# WARNING: new settings may not be used until builder is restarted

Tags: docker

When I run the following `docker buildx create`:

```
# Note: "$ " preceedes a line of input, "> " preceedes a line of output

$ docker buildx create \
  --name amd64_builder \
  --node amd64_builder \
  --platform linux/amd64 \
  "ssh://<MY_USER>@<IP>"

> WARNING: new settings may not be used until builder is restarted
> amd64_builder
```

it exits with `0` (does not fail), but produces the warning:

> WARNING: new settings may not be used until builder is restarted

and when I `docker buildx ls` my builders, I see it is indeed `inactive`:

```
$ docker buildx ls

> NAME/NODE       DRIVER/ENDPOINT          STATUS   BUILDKIT             PLATFORMS
> amd64_builder * remote
>   amd64_builder ssh://<MY_USER>@<IP>     inactive                      linux/amd64*
> default         docker
>   default       default                  running  v0.12.2+6560bb937e8c linux/arm64, > linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/mips64le, linux/mips64
> desktop-linux   docker
>   desktop-linux desktop-linux            running  v0.12.2+6560bb937e8c linux/arm64, linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/mips64le, linux/mips64
```

I am able to `ssh <MY_USER>@<IP>` (with all the valid `~/.ssh/config` in place).

---

**Question:** What is the meaning of `inactive`, and how do I properly *activate* my builder?